# React.js: Difference between these functions

Tags: reactjs

could someone explain the difference between these syntax:

```
function defineSchema(){

}
```

```
const defineSchema = () => {

}
```

```
const defineSchema = useCallback(() =>

})
```

And when should I use one?

A follow-up question on this would be how come when I try to change this variable

```
var schema = new passwordValidator();
```

I'm only able to change its value outside a function

And when inside a function, the changes does not take effect

e.g.

```
schema
  .is().min(8)                                    
  .is().max(20)                                   
  .has().symbols()                                
  .has().digits()                                 
  .has().not().spaces()                           
  .is().not().oneOf(simplePass);
```

The code above works, while the code below does not.

```
function defineSchema(passParamState){
schema
        .is().min(5)                                    
        .is().max(9)                                   
        .has().symbols()                                
        .has().digits()                                 
        .has().not().spaces()                           
        .is().not().oneOf(simplePass); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function defineSchema(){

}
```

This is how you would normally define a function in JS.
This function will also have its own `this`.
So use this method of definition, when you would want to have the context i.e `this`.

```
const defineSchema = () => {

}
```

This is another way to define functions in JS. 
This is known as arrow function, they got introduced in ES6.
They do not have their own `this`.
You can use this method of defining functions if you would want the function to inherit `this` from parent scope.

```
const memoizedCallback = useCallback(
  () => {
    doSomething(a, b);
  },
  [a, b], //dependencies.
);
```

`useCallback` is a hook that will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed.

From react docs:

> This is useful when passing callbacks to optimized child components that rely on reference equality to prevent unnecessary renders (e.g. shouldComponentUpdate).

So when you have some expensive computation in `doSomething` function, then you would want to use `useCallback`.

Answer (score 0):

@Utsav Patel's answer explained most of the differences. But there is an additional difference those declarations. Any functions that are declared using `function` (aka function declaration) get hosted to the top of the code.

For example the following code is going to print the value `test` to the console:

```
f('test');
function f(value) { console.log(value); }
```

while the following 2 examples will throw a `ReferenceError`.

```
f('test'); // f has not been declared yet
const f = function(value) { console.log(value); }
```

or

```
f('test'); // f has not been declared yet
const f = value => { console.log(value); }
```